# как убрать градиент у рамок кнопки?

Tags: css

Если приглядеться, то можно увидеть что рамка не полностью белого цвета, можно ли это как-то исправить?

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button')
let page = document.querySelector('.page')

button.onclick = function(){
    page.classList.toggle('dark-theme')
    page.classList.toggle('light-theme')
    button.classList.toggle('dark-theme')
    button.classList.toggle('light-theme')
}
```

```css
.button{        
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 48%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.light-theme{
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.dark-theme{
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
}

button.dark-theme{
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
    <title>Theme Changer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 </head>

 <body class="page dark-theme">
    <button class="button dark-theme">Click on me</button>   
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: зачем вам тему добавлять к кнопке? меняйте только у body

Comment: Я бы просто хотел, чтобы кнопка при темной теме была - белой, а при светлой - черной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.button{        
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 48%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #fff
}
```